# How to provide swagger/policy lik in terraform for Azure APIM Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-api-management, terraform-provider-azure

I am working on adding new API and adding new policies to the Azure APIM through terraform.
When I was testing in local(directly opening the terminal and run terraform plan and apply), I am able to get that created. But when I was going through the Azure devops pipeline, I am unable to track the file. I am getting the error "File doesn't exist".

Since I was using file command, I thought I will have to publish into artifacts and try that, but still same response. Do I have to put it into a storage account to make it accessible through SAS, is that the only option or I can work with pipeline [artifacts](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_api_operation_policy).

Here is the TF code - commented out is multiple version I have tried.

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "example" {
  name                = "example-api1"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_api_management.example.resource_group_name
  api_management_name = data.azurerm_api_management.example.name
  revision            = "1"
  display_name        = "Example API1"
  path                = "example1"
  protocols           = ["https"]
  service_url         = "http://123.0.0.0:8000"
  subscription_required  = true

  import {
    content_format = "openapi+json"
    # content_value  = file("$(Pipeline.Workspace)/Artifacts/swagger/sample_swagger.json")
    # content_value  = file("/Artifacts/swagger/sample_swagger.json")  -- **this works in local**
    xml_link   = "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/Artifacts/swagger/sample_swagger.json"
  }
}
```

pipeline task:

```
- task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-release-task.TerraformTaskV2@2
  displayName: 'Terraform : plan'
  inputs:
    command: plan
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TerraForm'
    environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'ps-vs-sc'
    backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: '$(rgName)'
    backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: $(strName)
    backendAzureRmContainerName: $(containerName)
    backendAzureRmKey: '$(storagekey)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I am able to make the script working is, uploading the swagger json to storage account and generate the link with SAS. Its working fine with that approach.